# Finding the size of this charger plug

Tags: power-supply, battery-charging, identification, cables, plug

Does anyone know how to identify the correct size of this plug?

I have a pair of heated gloves (-10°F in Boston last night!). They don’t work any more any I’m hoping that the problem is in my charging cable. Does anyone know how to find the size plug based on the info in the pics below?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: 2.1 mm diameter?

Comment: looks like the insulating tube pulled out of the cable connector ... it may be inside the battery connector ... you could make a temporary replacement by rolling a tube out of paper and inserting it into the cable connector

Answer (score 1):

That is a run-of-the-mill barrel connector whose plastic sheath has broken (gee, wonder why).

The controlling dimensions of a barrel connector are the outside diameter which is intact, and the inside diameter which is also intact.

Back in the day I would just measure those and head down to Radio Shack,  but now you have to mail order it from Mouser, Digi-Key etc.

First, look at the cable and see if one edge or the other is distinctive - marking, ribbed edge, that sort of thing.  If not, mark it with something.
You'll need to cut the connector off the cable and attach the wires to the new connector.  Leave enough wire on the old connector that you can beep out which wire inside the cable goes to "shell" and which to "tip".   Putting reverse voltage on a lithium battery would be really, really bad.

I would do your first charge session in a metal pot on a stove top or sink.

If the battery starts to catch fire, don't panic. Just stay cool as a cucumber, pick up the pot, and slow-walk it outside and dump it in the snow. The important thing is not do a jerky panicked move and flip it off the pot and onto a flammable couch or something.

Answer (score 1):

How about a caliper?

Measuring the outer diameter is simple.

Pin diameter: If you can't reach it with the caliper search something that looks similar thick as the pin that slides in smoothly to the jack. Again use the caliper.

It will be one of the [typical sizes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coaxial_power_connector#Common_sizes_and_interchangeability) (there are many :)